# How to pick out span tag that doesn't have a class

Tags: javascript, html

Using `document.getElementsByClassName("span3 pickItem").outerHTML)` I set a variable **htmlData** to contain:

```
<div itemscope="" class="span3 pickItem">
     <p itemprop="name" class="name">
          <a href="/user/view?id=4943">
               <span>John Doe</span>
               <br />
               <span>'Arizona'</span>
               <br />
               <span>'Student'</span>
          </a>
     </p>
</div>
```

How can I pick each value from the span tag and console.log them as such:

`console.log(...span[0])`   output: `John Doe`

`console.log(...span[1])`   output: `Arizona`

`console.log(...span[2])`   output: `Student`

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like this

```
let namesArr = []; 
let name = document.querySelectorAll("span");
name.forEach(function(names) {
   namesArr.push(names.innerHTML);//Stores all names in array so you can access later 
});
console.log(namesArr[0]);
console.log(namesArr[1]);
console.log(namesArr[2]);
```

Comment: And how do I set the function to extract it from the variable htmlData?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```js
// console log all names
const items = document.querySelectorAll('div.pickItem span')
items.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.innerText)
})

// console each from array index
console.log(items[0].innerText)
console.log(items[1].innerText)
console.log(items[2].innerText)
```

Comment: And how do I set the function to extract it from the variable htmlData?

Comment: well then you can just replace this `document.querySelectorAll('div.pickItem span')` with the variable i guess, since you have the dom populated already in there

Comment: Doesn't work, could you edit your code to show

Answer (score 0):

```
let spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

console.log(spans[0].innerHTML); //'Joe Doe'
```

Comment: And how do I set the function to extract it from the variable htmlData?

Comment: It would depend on how you set the variable. For example: Is the html in a string?

Comment: No, it's still parsed as html in the variable htmlData. But I could stringify it

Comment: For console.log to work it would have to be output in html in a browser, so output the html and then use console.log? You would use spans.foreach( item => { console.log(item.innerHTML):}) to output all of the spans.

Comment: I don't think people really understood my question. The variable htmlData stores the html I posted. Now using the varialbe htmlData how  would I extract data from the spans **from** the varible htmlData. extract values from the variable and not browser

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

> You don't even need the `htmlData` variable because the DOM elements already exist. If you want to learn about parsing a string of HTML (this is what your `htmlData` variable has in it) into DOM elements, you can reivew [`DOMParser.parseFromString()` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString).

1. Select the `a`nchor
2. Select its child `span`s and map their `textContent` properties

```js
function getTextFromSpan (span) {
  // Just return the text as-is:
  // return span.textContent?.trim() ?? '';

  // Or, you can also remove the single quotes from the text value if they exist:
  const text = span.textContent?.trim() ?? '';
  const singleQuote = `'`;
  const hasQuotes = text.startsWith(singleQuote) && text.endsWith(singleQuote);
  return hasQuotes ? text.slice(1, -1) : text;
}

const anchor = document.querySelector('div.span3.pickItem > p.name > a');

const spanTexts = [...anchor.querySelectorAll(':scope > span')].map(getTextFromSpan);

for (const text of spanTexts) {
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<div itemscope="" class="span3 pickItem">
  <p itemprop="name" class="name">
    <a href="/user/view?id=4943">
      <span>John Doe</span>
      <br />
      <span>'Arizona'</span>
      <br />
      <span>'Student'</span>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```